# How to open a new tab in browsers using Selenium+Java?

Tags: selenium

I find some answers but they do not work. Common one is this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

But this is not working. can you help me?

And also I did not understand why we use `(By.cssSelector("body"))` above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javaScript :

```
String a = "window.open('about:blank','_blank');";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(a);
```

or with a URL:

```
String a = "window.open('http://google.com','');";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(a);
```